# Official Microsoft Project installer

Tags: windows, installation, ms-project

Where can I find the official Microsoft Project installer that is not an ISO file?
I already have a license key.

I'm just looking for something like an `.EXE` or `.MSI` or `.MSM` where I can just double click and install it.

Comment: I think your question is not about programming, so is not fit to ask here ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [How to extract the contents from an .ISO file without burning the .ISO to disc.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2011/04/19/how-to-extract-the-contents-from-an-iso-file-without-burning-the-iso-to-disc.aspx) article which explains how to extract the content.